# Generate a sequence of square numbers till 10

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-function, generate, mysql-function

How to generate a sequence of SQUARE numbers till 10 in MYSQL? (1^2,2^2, etc)

I was only able to generate a numerical sequence from 1 to 10.

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (n + 1) FROM cte WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT n FROM cte;
```

But if I add the POW() function, the result will be

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT POW((n + 1),2) FROM cte WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT n FROM cte;
```

RESULT:
1
4
25

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to square the resul of the cte

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte (n) AS
(
  SELECT 1
  UNION ALL
  SELECT (n + 1) FROM cte WHERE n < 10
)
SELECT POW(n,2) FROM cte;
```

| POW(n,2) |
| --- |
| 1 |
| 4 |
| 9 |
| 16 |
| 25 |
| 36 |
| 49 |
| 64 |
| 81 |
| 100 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/r9r9ewh3)

Comment: So the square should be added to the result? not in the WITH construction?

Comment: yes as you want the square from the integers 1 till 10, you need first generate then numbers and the square them as you can see in the fiddle.